# Topological properties of shortest paths

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request

Suppose we have a manifold $M$ equipped with a reasonable notion of arc length $l(\cdot)$ for smooth paths. I guess by "reasonable" I mean at least that $l(0)=0$, $l(a+b)=l(a)+l(b)$, and $l(p)$ varies continuously as $p$ moves along a homotopy. (Maybe more requirements are appropriate - we could even require that $l$ is realizable as the standard geometric arc length via an embedding of $M$ in Euclidean space.) Say that $p$ is a shortest path if $l(p)\le l(q)$ for every path $q$ that has the same endpoints as $p$.

**Does the statement "$p$ is a shortest path" convey any topological information about $p$?** That is, is there a topologically-invariant set of paths that contains all shortest paths (but not all simple paths)? [Edited to add "simple", since it was pointed out in a comment that all shortest paths are simple (i.e. non-self-intersecting).]

Another approach to the question might be: order the fundamental group of $M$ by comparing minimal path lengths: $x\le y$ iff $\inf\{l(p):p\in x\}\le\inf\{l(p):p\in y\}$. Is there any necessary relationship between this order structure and the algebraic structure of $\pi_1(M)$? For example, is $p\le p^2$ for every class $p$? [I guess the observation about non-simple paths answers this in some cases, e.g. if $M\cong I\times S^1$.]

I suspect the answer to all of the above is no, because I can vaguely imagine contriving an embedding of $M$ that "favors" a selected [simple] path (and a small neighborhood of similar paths) so as to make it shorter than those in any other homotopy class. I wouldn't be surprised if an approach like this could even produce an embedding realizing an arbitrary list of desired order data.

On the other hand, it's intuitively true that if e.g. a torus is geometrically nice enough, then going around it once (along a generator of the fundamental group) should be shorter than going around it in the same direction ten times. I'm curious what work has been done to find "niceness" conditions (on the arc-length data or whatever determines it) that enable this kind of reasoning.

Comment: If you are interested in representatives of homotopy classes of least length, you need to change your requirement to locally-shortest path. The constant map will always have less length than a nontrivial loop.

Comment: Shortest paths are always simple.

Comment: @AlexNolte I'm not sure I follow, since the constant map has different endpoints than a path between two different points. I'm wondering whether the statement "$p$ is the shortest among all paths from $a$ to $b$" constrains which homotopy class $p$ belongs to (allowing only homotopies that fix the endpoints, as in the fundamental groupoid).

Comment: @Karl, I'm referring to your discussion of shortest representatives of elements of the fundamental group (which represent closed paths).

Comment: Ah yeah, my earlier definition of "shortest path" isn't relevant there - I'll edit to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: A relevant fact is that closed geodesics on closed hyperbolic surfaces always have minimal self-intersection.

Comment: Right, I guess that generalizes Moishe's comment and answers my original question affirmatively. The relationship between homotopy class and self-intersection is something I've never thought about and seems interesting. On the other hand, self-intersection can't be the whole story (considering the torus, where most elements of the fundamental group have simple representatives), so I wonder what else can be said topologically about shortest paths.

Comment: Are you assuming that your "length" comes from a Finsler metric or a Riemannian metric? If not, the next best thing to consider is a "[path-metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)." I very much doubt you will get a reasonable answer in this degree of generality however. In the setting of smooth Riemannian metrics, a reasonable thing to consider is a foliation of the tangent bundle by some smooth paths, such that the family of paths is stable under affine reparameterization, plus some conditions guaranteeing existence of a unit tangent bundle.

Comment: I suggest you spend more time thinking about what is it that you are actually interested in.

Comment: Agreed - my background on the topic is pretty weak, so I was just curious about what's known. Your input is enlightening! I think I'll focus on trying to flesh out my argument that every simple path can be a shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I know along the lines of your question:

Let $X$ be a locally compact, metrizable, locally connected space and $\alpha$ is a simple arc in $X$, i.e. a subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Then $X$ can be metrized using a complete path-metric $d$ for which $\alpha$ is a geodesic (distance-minimizing) arc.

When $X$ is compact, this is a consequence of Theorem 1 in

*Bing, R. H.*, [**A convex metric for a locally connected continuum**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1949-09298-4), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 55, 812-819 (1949). [ZBL0035.10801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0035.10801).

For locally-compact spaces, one uses the main result in

*Dooley, Robert A.*, [**Further extending a complete convex metric**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2039419), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 40, 590-596 (1973). [ZBL0267.54031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0267.54031).

which is a generalization of Bing's work.

For instance, this applies in the case when $X$ is a manifold; however, the arc $\alpha$ can be wild (non-smoothable).